# WCF windows authentication doesn't work after deploy

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5

I have WCF service with windows authentication. After deploying it to another server I received the following exception:

`System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized       with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`

The client configuration doesn't changed and looks like this:

```
<ws2007HttpBinding>
  <binding name="autoSecureBinding">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</ws2007HttpBinding>
```

EDIT: When I open my service in browser I receive the following error:

`Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.`

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is another server under the same active directory domain?

Also You want to go to target IIS and see if Site / Application Authentication settings have "Windows Authentication" set to "Enabled". (See screens for IIS7 below)
[image: Authentication settings icon]

[image: Enable window authentication]

Comment: Windows Authentication is enabled and Anonymous is disabled.
That new server is in the same AD domain.

Comment: Hmm, apparently error messages state, that Anonymous should be enabled... Don't really know if enabling is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working web.config of a Win auth only WCF service that I am using (Only Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyBindingForWindowsAuth">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />-->
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="DataAccessService.Service">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingForWindowsAuth" contract="DataAccessService.IService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingForWindowsAuth" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this setup in place, if you want to pass ASP.NET user identity to WCF you have 3 options:

Option 1:

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("phil.morris", "P4ssW0rd", "mydomain");
```

Option 2:

Use impersonate:

```
using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
{
    string s = client.GetUserInfo();
    retVal = "Wcf User: " + s;
}
```

Option 3:
ENABLE ASP.NET Impersonation in the caller ASP.NET application